# ANTLR4- dynamically inject token

Tags: parsing, antlr4

So I'm writing a python parser and I need to dynamically generate `INDENT` and `DEDENT` tokens (because python doesn't use explicit delimiters) according to the [python grammar specification](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation).

Basically I have a stack of integers representing indentation levels. In an embedded Java action in the `INDENT` token, I check if the current level of indentation is higher than the level on top of the stack; if it is, I push it on; if not, I call `skip()`.

The problem is, if the current indentation level matches a level multiple levels down in the stack, I have to generate multiple `DEDENT` tokens, and I can't figure out how to do that.

My current code: (note that `within_indent_block` and `current_indent_level` are managed elsewhere)

```
fragment DENT: {within_indent_block}? (SPACE|TAB)+;

INDENT: {within_indent_block}? DENT
        {if(current_indent_level > whitespace_stack.peek().intValue()){
                 whitespace_stack.push(new Integer(current_indent_level));
                 within_indent_block = false;
         }else{
                 skip();
         }
         }
         ;    

DEDENT: {within_indent_block}? DENT
        {if(current_indent_level < whitespace_stack.peek().intValue()){
            while(current_indent_level < whitespace_stack.peek().intValue()){
                      whitespace_stack.pop();
                      <<injectDedentToken()>>; //how do I do this
            }
         }else{
               skip();
         }
         }
         ;
```

How do I do this and / or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code you have posted.

1. The `INDENT` and `DEDENT` rules are semantically identical (considering predicates and rule references, but ignoring actions). Since `INDENT` appears first, this means you can *never* have a token produced by the `DEDENT` rule is this grammar.
2. The `{within_indent_block}?` predicate appears before you reference `DENT` as well as inside the `DENT` fragment rule itself. This duplication serves no purpose but will slow down your lexer.

The actual handling of post-matching actions is best placed in an override of [`Lexer.nextToken()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#nextToken%28%29). For example, you could start with something like the following.

```
private final Deque<Token> pendingTokens = new ArrayDeque<>();

@Override
public Token nextToken() {
    while (pendingTokens.isEmpty()) {
        Token token = super.nextToken();
        switch (token.getType()) {
        case INDENT:
            // handle indent here. to skip this token, simply don't add
            // anything to the pendingTokens queue and super.nextToken()
            // will be called again.
            break;

        case DEDENT:
            // handle indent here. to skip this token, simply don't add
            // anything to the pendingTokens queue and super.nextToken()
            // will be called again.
            break;

        default:
            pendingTokens.add(token);
            break;
        }
    }

    return pendingTokens.poll();
}
```