# AnTLR4: INDENT and DEDENT tokens

Tags: python, grammar, lexer, antlr4

I am implementing Python grammar in AnTLR4 but I am facing the same problem with INDENT and DEDENT discussed here: [ANTLR4- dynamically inject token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158474/antlr4-dynamically-inject-token#new-answer)

The solution I am trying is to convert the solution by Ter that can be found here http://antlr3.org/grammar/1078018002577/python.tar.gz (override nextToken and insert imaginary tokens).

The problem is that this solution assumes that we have a lexer rule like:

```
LEADING_WS
    :   {getColumn()==1}?
        // match spaces or tabs, tracking indentation count
        (   ' '  { spaces++; }
        |   '\t' { spaces += 8; spaces -= (spaces % 8); }
        |   '\014' // formfeed is ok
        )+
        {
        }
        ...
```

but I keep getting an error because actions in lexer rule must be last element on single altermost alternative.

can anyone help me to find a solution?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sorry for the shameless plug, but I had the same issue and decided to write a helper class for it: [antlr-denter](https://github.com/yshavit/antlr-denter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your calculation involving `spaces` to either the end of the `LEADING_WS` rule or your implementation of `nextToken`. At the end of `LEADING_WS` it could look like the following.

```
LEADING_WS
  : {getColumn()==1}?
    // match spaces or tabs, tracking indentation count
    [ \t]+
    {spaces = computeSpaces(_input.getText());}
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying the solution of putting it on the overridden implementation of nextToken!

Comment: For curiosity I tested the solution you propose but I am getting that $text is not allowed in lexer actions! Am I using it right?

Comment: @pinker sorry about that, you have to use `_input.getText()` instead of `$text` in ANTLR 4.